# adding accessorytype without using the delegates

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

is there a way to add cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
to each row in a table without using delegate tableView functions?(the reason for this is a bit complicated..)

im thinking on stuff like

```
for(UITableViewCell *cell in TheTable){
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
}
```

but this wont work..
any ideas?

ty in advance!

Comment: What is `TheTable`? Is it the `tableView` or an array?

Comment: TheTable is just an tableView

Comment: Did you implement a data source?

Comment: Yes i did, the table is filled with rows of information about VM's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never have access to all the cells from the `UITableView` object. You can access the visible cells like @Jhaliya mentioned. Of course your best approach here is to have a `BOOL` instance variable to keep track of whether cells have the detail disclosure button and flip them.

BOOL isDetailDisclosureAccessoryVisible;

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`,

```
if ( isDetailDisclosureAccessoryVisible ) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

When you want to make them available,

```
isDetailDisclosureAccessoryVisible = YES;
[TheTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[TheTable indexPathsForVisibleRows]
                WithRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; //Choose an appropriate animation here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by accessing the `UITableViewCell` in an functions defined by you.

There are number of function in `UITableView` which you could use to access the `UITableViewCell` outside the delegate functions.

```
- (NSArray *)visibleCells;
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForRowsInRect:(CGRect)rect;
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows;
```

To access a cell for a given indexPath use the below method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

For more read [UITabelView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) apple doc.